# Javascript global error handling (not work on ie 9)

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to catch every error in javascript and log server side.

core.js (on first line)

```
// Global error javascript log
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line)
{
    try
    {
        // Send error to server via AJAX Request
        var x = new (this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        x.open('POST', '/jserrorlog.php', 1);
        x.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        x.send('Msg='+msg+'&Url='+url+'&Line='+line);

        x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(x.readyState > 3 && x.status == 200)
                window.console && console.log(x.responseText);
        };
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        window.console && console.log(e);
    }
};
```

jserrorlog.php (Server Side)

```
<?php
    // log error on server
    $Msg  = (isset($_POST['Msg']))  ? $_POST['Msg']  : null;
    $Url  = (isset($_POST['Url']))  ? $_POST['Url']  : null;
    $Line = (isset($_POST['Line'])) ? $_POST['Line'] : null;

    echo ( error_log('Javascript Error:'.$Msg.'; Url:'.$Url.'; Line:'.$Line) ) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976144.aspx

**Handling Errors via the window.onerror DHTML Event**

> A common problem that bites many developers occurs when their onerror
>   handler is not called because they have script debugging enabled for
>   Internet Explorer. This will be the case by default if you have
>   installed the Microsoft Script Debugger or Microsoft Visual Studio
>   6.0® (specifically Visual InterDev 6.0™)—onerror handling is how these products launch their debugger. You can disable script debugging for a
>   given instance of Internet Explorer on the Advanced tab of the
>   Internet Options dialog box (note that checking the Disable script
>   debugging setting will apply only to that instance of Internet
>   Explorer)

**Disable script debugging to invoke your own onerror handler**

> It should be clear from this discussion that you can catch both syntax
>   and run-time errors using a window.onerror handler. However, I only
>   told you this so that you would understand how it works, not so that
>   you would intentionally allow syntax errors in your production Web
>   pages. All syntax errors can, and should, be eliminated during the
>   development phase. Besides, onerror handling doesn't even work for
>   VBScript syntax errors (as noted below), and there is no way to catch
>   server-side syntax errors in any language.

**Disable script debugging on IE**

1. In Internet Explorer, choose Internet Options from the Tools menu.
2. In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
3. On the Advanced tab, under Browsing, clear Disable Script Debugging.
4. Click OK.