# MVC 5 routing post details without id in the url but the title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have seen this so many times but I have no idea how this can be built. For example stackoverflow, when you click a question the url will be something like this:

```
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543928/javascript-global-error-handling-not-work-on-ie-9`
```

Basically will open that question `javascript global error handlling ...`

How can you achieve this:

```
- for users: http://site/profile/username
- for posts: http://site/post/just-a-post-example
- for messages: http://site/message/my-custom-message
```

etc, etc etc

Comment: It's a matter of setting up correct routing rules. Look for `ASP.NET MVC routing` in your favorite search engine and you should find what you're looking for

Comment: Take a look at this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC